# Are vendor prefixes required for "none"?

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

Just a quick question about vendor prefixes that I've been wondering about but couldn't find the answer to - are they required when turning off/resetting the style with "none", "initial", "0", etc?  For example, if I set a box shadow like this:

```
   -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
   -moz-box-shadow: -4px 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
   box-shadow: -4px 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
```

If I didn't want the box shadow at a smaller screen size, in the media query would I do simply do "box-shadow: none;" or do I need to do:

```
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
```

Comment: Are you sure you need them at all? Those browsers have worked with those unprefixed forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set your box-shadow like this...

```
-webkit-box-shadow: -4px 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
-moz-box-shadow: -4px 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
box-shadow: -4px 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
```

... you'll need to unset it like this :

```
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```

Otherwise, browsers that don't support the non-prefixed version of `box-shadow` won't know that you're setting your `box-shadow` to `none`, just like they won't know that you're setting your `box-shadow` to `-4px 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)` if you only use the non-prefixed version.

Comment: That's what I thought but I just wanted to double check.  Accepted answer. Thanks!